# Complex pattern substitution in Makefile prerequisites

Tags: dependencies, makefile, build-automation

I’ve got the following directory structure:

```
./
 |- obj/
 |--- debug/
 |--- release/
 |- bin/
 |--- debug/
 |--- release/
 |- src/
 |--- main.c
 |--- libb/
 |----- foo.c
 |- include/
 |--- libb/
 |----- foo.h
```

Furthermore, I manually specify dependencies of individual objects in my `Makefile` in the following format (example):

```
 main_DEPS = libb/foo
```

Now I want to be able to type `make bin/debug/main`, and this generates the necessary dependencies and target file:

- `obj/debug/libb/foo.o`
- `obj/debug/main.o`
- `bin/debug/main`

**How do I do that?** My current approach is extremely convoluted and incomplete:

- The following creates the object files. However, it fails to create any necessary subfolders (`libb`) if they don’t yet exist. It also doesn’t keep track of any changed header files. The [Makefile tutorial trick to generate prerequisites automatically](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Prerequisites) could be adapted maybe?

  ```
  CFLAGS+=-I include

  obj/*/%.o: src/%.cpp
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
  ```
- The following tries to resolve the dependencies of a binary and built it from all required object files. But I have no idea how to retrieve those object files from the `*_DEPS` variable.

  ```
  .SECONDEXPANSION:

  bin/debug/%: obj/debug/%.o $(patsubst %,obj/debug/%.o,$($(patsubst bin/debug/%,%,$@)_DEPS))
      $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $< $(patsubst %,obj/debug/%.o,$($(patsubst bin/debug/%,%,$@)_DEPS)) -o $@

  bin/release/%: obj/release/%.o $(patsubst %,obj/release/%.o,$($(patsubst bin/release/%,%,$@)_DEPS))
      $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $< $(patsubst %,obj/release/%.o,$($(patsubst bin/release/%,%,$@)_DEPS)) -o $@
  ```

  Unfortunately, this doesn’t build dependencies automatically: it just complains “obj/debug/libb/foo.o: No such file or directory” – but it works weirdly enough if I built this file manually using `mkdir obj/debug/libb; make obj/debug/libb/foo.o`.

  It’s also hopelessly complicated and uses gratuitous code duplication (which I cannot get rid of without making it even more complex).

What’s the least complicated solution for this? In principle I’m not opposed to using something other than `make` if it’s widely available (autoconf …) but I prefer keeping the effort (and new learning required) to a minimum and from what I’ve seen so far all other build systems seem to be vastly more complex than `make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** in response to [chat message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3604699#3604699)

> *@sehe It makes it slightly easier, yes … but the duplication is still there, and the problem of not building the dependencies as well*

I have found a verbose, but effective (non-complex) way to to make it work with submake calls (*in a single Makefile*).

We have the 'outer make' that contains just a single rule and the dependency definitions

```
A_DEPS=dep1 dep2
C_DEPS=dep2

##########################
# "outer" Make
bin/%/A bin/%/B bin/%/C:
    $(MAKE) BUILD="$*" TARGET=$(@F) DEPS="$($(@F)_DEPS)" GENRULE
```

In effect, we translate the 'deduced' information into explicit variables on sub-call to make. The rest of the Makefile contains the definition of our '*generic target rule*', `GENRULE`:

```
##########################
# "inner" Make

%/*.o:
    mkdir -p "$(@D)" && touch "$@"

GENRULE: obj/$(BUILD)/$(TARGET).o $(DEPS:%=obj/$(BUILD)/%.o) 
    echo gcc -o "bin/$(BUILD)/$(TARGET)" $^
    mkdir -p "bin/$(BUILD)" && touch "bin/$(BUILD)/$(TARGET)"
.PHONY: GENRULE
```

Again, a test run:

```
$ for target in bin/{debug,release}/{A,B,C}; do make -Bs "$target"; done

gcc -o bin/debug/A obj/debug/A.o obj/debug/dep1.o obj/debug/dep2.o
gcc -o bin/debug/B obj/debug/B.o
gcc -o bin/debug/C obj/debug/C.o obj/debug/dep2.o
gcc -o bin/release/A obj/release/A.o obj/release/dep1.o obj/release/dep2.o
gcc -o bin/release/B obj/release/B.o
gcc -o bin/release/C obj/release/C.o obj/release/dep2.o
```

The objects have all been created:

```
$ find bin obj

bin
bin/debug
bin/debug/A
bin/debug/B
bin/debug/C
bin/release
bin/release/A
bin/release/B
bin/release/C
obj
obj/debug
obj/debug/A.o
obj/debug/B.o
obj/debug/C.o
obj/debug/dep1.o
obj/debug/dep2.o
obj/release
obj/release/A.o
obj/release/B.o
obj/release/C.o
obj/release/dep1.o
obj/release/dep2.o
```

---

For simple variables (non-dependencies) here's a simple example using the $@ and $(@F) *automatic variables*:

```
EXTRA="--standardopts"
A_FLAGS="--a-opts"
B_FLAGS="--b-opts"

.SECONDEXPANSION:
    
debug/% release/%: EXTRA+=$($(@F)_FLAGS)

%/A %/B %/C:
    echo building $@ with $(EXTRA)
```